# Git repo with production branch only (no development history)

Tags: git, release

I searched a bit but found only solutions to similarly sounding problems. So, is it possible to have a remote repo containing only `Production` (or whatever you like to call it) branch and no reference to commits on other branches which were merged into `Production`? We would never make fast forward merges so the `Production` branch would have only release commits which are intended to be actually published.

The goal is to restrict access only to proper releases without the development history and intermediary progress. I tried to look for restricting branch access but found only references to protecting branches from writing to not reading from. I *do* realise that this may be somewhat against the purpose of Git itself and I may simply upload release packages somewhere but if it's possible it seems both easier and more disk space/network efficient to save it incrementally.

The workaround I can imagine is to have a second local repo where I would copy and commit only current release code but it's a Plan B for now. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you are trying to solve. Does having the additional commits available in production cause any problems? Anyway, if you don't want any history, you can use rsync to be even more bandwidth-efficient than you could ever be with the git protocol.

Comment: Search for "git squash". Basically and oversimplified: you develop on a branch with all the history as it goes. When it is done, you merge that branch to production by squashing all the branch commits into a single one. You then push only that production branch on your reference remote.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I would like to have history but limited to release commits. We're trying to have a sort of 'front end' repo with no 'in progress' stuff. It's a bit of a whim surely but I would like to know if its possible with git. :-)

Comment: @Zeitounator I imagine you would also have to rebase the squashed commit onto the `Production` branch? Thanks for the tip I'll look into that.

Comment: @konrad You can simply use `git merge --squash`, with no rebasing required, if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can "detach" the history of your release branch by always using squash merges. Everytime you want to merge a branch that is not supposed to be visible on the release repo, you can use commands similar to these:

```
git checkout release
git merge --squash cool-feature-branch
git commit -m "Release cool feature."
```

Alternatively, you can clean up an existing release branch and keep only the "main line" commits with `filter-branch`:

```
git checkout release
git filter-branch --parent-filter 'read a b rest; echo $a $b' -- --first-parent
```

This command enumerates the commits on the release branch by only following the first parent of each commit, and rewrites these commits with only a single parent. The end result is that the branch becomes "detached" from all branches that have been merged (except for fast-forward merges, which are indistinguishable from commits directly committed to the branch).

Once you have prepared a release branch containing only the commits you want to be visible to your customer, you can use `git log release` to verify the list of commits, and `git push <remote> release` to push the release branch. This will only push the commits shown by `git log`.